# Как продолжить скачивание Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, установка, visual-studio-2017, дистрибутив

Скачал онлайн-инсталлятор VS2017 и для скачивания оффлайн-дистрибутива выполил

```
vs_community__1293449728.1509666682.exe --layout "D:\VS 2017\Files [vs_community__1293449728.1509666682]"
```

Проблема в том, что скачалось 32 ГБ и произошла какая-то ошибка:

[image: скриншот]

Как продолжить скачивание? Будет ли правильно просто выполнить ту же команду ещё раз? Окно, судя по всему, закрылось при оскриншочивании.

Comment: О, а поделитесь, как его собрать - оффлайн-дистрибутив - а то что-то моего интеллекта продраться через документации не хватило. Хочу просто эдакий минимум для C++ с Windows SDK собрать...

Comment: @Harry, понятия не имею, я хотел всё выкачать.

Comment: Жаль... А то вроде как на отдельный вопрос не тянет... (Или - как к модератору, кстати, поздравляю :) - тянет?)

Comment: @Harry, там [инструкция на несколько экранов](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-certificates-for-visual-studio-offline) с какой-то установкой сертификатов и ещё уймой всякой магии. У меня ощущение, что она на десяток вопросов потянет. А я просто хочу скачать полный инсталлятор оффлайновый - пошёл по инструкции с ютьюба. Не прокатило. Ненавижу онлайн-инсталляторы от майкросовта - ни разу с ними ничего хорошего не понлучилось.

Comment: Ото ж и оно... :(